# AJAX call to render partial in Rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user's dashboard page where the left side has a sidebar with links like Projects, Blogs, etc. I want to be able to click a link such as the "Projects" link and then in the main area, the view for projects would load up (view would be a bullet list of projects) without having to refresh the page. I'm trying to make this happen with AJAX, but things are not working.

Here's how I think it's supposed to work. The user clicks on the sidebar link in `show.html.erb`

```
<%= link_to 'Projects', '/dash', remote: true %>
```

where `/dash` is configured to route to users#show in the `config/routes.rb` file like this:

```
match '/dash' => 'users#show'
```

And then, the `show` action is called in`users_controller.rb` controller:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @projects = @user.projects

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # renders show.html.erb
      format.js   # renders show.js.erb
    end
end
```

Where `show.js.erb` is executed. My `show.js.erb` file has this one line:

```
$('#ajax').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'projects/index')).html_safe %>");
```

And that is supposed to modify the #ajax div in my `show.html.erb`:

```
<div id="ajax">
  <%= render :template => 'projects/index' %>
</div>
```

The `app/views/projects/index.html.rb` takes in @projects and gives a list, like this:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <p><%= project.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

Obviously, I'm doing things wrong because this is not working. What am I doing wrong? Is there some code I need to change elsewhere? I'm on Rails 3.2.13, so the lines `//=jquery` and `//=jquery_ujs` under `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` should have imported the necessary jQuery and AJAX functionality.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that in your `show.js.erb` file you are trying to render a partial but you are passing it a file that is not a partial. Partial files begin with an underscore `_`.

So, to avoid duplicating code, here's what I'd do:

```
# app/views/projects/show.js.erb
$('#ajax').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'index', :locals => { :projects => @projects } ) %>");

# app/views/projects/index.html.erb
<%= render :partial => 'index', :locals => { :projects => @projects } %>

# app/views/projects/**_**index.html.erb
# Include here the code that you previously had in index.html.erb
# Don't forget to change @projects to projects
<% projects.each do |project| %>
  <p><%= project.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

Also, you shouldn't use `match` in your routes, as you pretty much will never need your routes to be accessible by both GET and POST methods. So try to use `get` instead of `match`.